# if button press (gpio, raspberry) send a new page/html to browser(client) with node.js (server), how do?

Tags: node.js

I have a `webserver.js` file (using `nodejs`, `express`, `socket` and `npm pigpio`) and an `index.html` with a slider function.
With the slider function, I can control `gpios/pwm` on my `raspberry`, and this works fine.

Now I want to load another HTML page to the client(browser) if a GPIO input is detected (button press) but I don't know how to implement such a function in the `webserver.js`?

Does somebody have an idea, is this possible?

Comment: Can you share the code you tried to archive that ?

Comment: for example I tried follow code:
app.get(function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('test.html', {__dirname + '/public/draw/');